# Arcgis javascript route path draw event

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is it possible to capture the draw event of the route paths? Given that each route path/polyline will not have the same color eg. some indications that its a ramp, outdoor, indoor (color coding) styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is also resolve, the workaround was to customize the data of the route dataset table contains floor/typeID. Then when the NA/route service returns the route instructions, there is a 'string' key of each feature item from the json objects returned. We can get the type/floor(any schema you design) to process it in the frontend to do the customisation of the graphics objects.